# How to rename files according to a .CSV map

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, csv, rename

Data science roadblock here... I need to rename 972 files according to a .csv file that has multiples attributes of those 972 files.

They share one thing in common which are the values of `Image Data ID` column. 
In the file name this number (6 digits) is present in the last part of the name right before ".nii"

I have loaded the .csv file into a Pandas datafreme. Here's an example of what it looks like:

```
    Image Data ID   Subject Group   Visit   Description
516 277576  027_S_2245  EMCI    4   ACCELERATED SAG IR-SPGR
525 342645  027_S_2183  EMCI    4   ACCELERATED SAG IR-SPGR
1   292394  131_S_0123  CN  26  Accelerated SAG IR-SPGR
3   475763  131_S_0123  CN  32  Accelerated SAG IR-SPGR
4   413872  131_S_0123  CN  30  Accelerated SAG IR-SPGR
```

Perhaps more understandable in an image format:

[image]

The filenames are listed in a list, done with:

```
files = os.listdir("path/to/files")
```

Here's an example of what the file names are like:

```
ADNI_098_S_4215_MR_Sag_IR-SPGR__br_raw_20130206130502189_10_S173103_I343697.nii
ADNI_094_S_2201_MR_Accelerated_SAG_IR-SPGR__br_raw_20120119112855332_188_S137442_I279199.nii
ADNI_127_S_4240_MR_Sag_IR-SPGR__br_raw_20120925151831011_194_S168683_I336697.nii
```

Thus, in essence what I want to do is identify a file in its respective .CSV row through the value of `Image Data ID` and rename it like:

```
EMCI_027_S_2245_4_Accelerated.nii
```

or

```
CN_134_S_0233_32_Normal.nii
```

(Depending if `Description` has the word Accelerated or not)

Any suggestions on how to approach this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what i can see, here's what I would suggest :

-Make a function that extracts the image_data_id from the old_name of the file (If all your id are of the same size(size 6 from what i can see here), you can do name_file[-11,-5] to extract the id from a string called name_file, if not, you can do regex(find the number between I and .nii)). Let's call that function id_from_file_name.

-Now let's call df_id the dataframe obtained by loading your csv file. Do

```
import os
df_calc = df_id.set_index('Image_Data_Id')

def new_name_file(old_name):
    id = id_from_file_name(old_name)
    # Edit : Related to first comment, changed id to int(id)
    if int(id) not in df_calc.index:
        print( id, 'not in dataframe')
        return None
    if 'accelerated' in df_calc.loc[id, 'Description'].lower():
        type = 'Accelerated'
    else:
        type = 'Normal'
    return(f'{df_calc.loc[id,'Group']}_{df_calc.loc[id,'Subject']}_{df_calc.loc[id,'Visit']}_{type}.nii')

list_name = os.listdir(path)
for i in list_name:
    new_name = new_name_file(i)
    if new_name is not None:
        os.rename(path/old_name, path/dict_name(old_name))
```

Edit : To create that function id_from_file_name, you can do :

```
import re
def id_from_file_name(name):
    return(re.search(r'I(.*?).nii', name).group(1))
```

Comment: Something's not quite right... As a test I'm doing `In: new_name_file(files[0])
Out: 343697 not in dataframe`

But then I do `In: 343697 in df_calc.index
Out: True`

Comment: You're absolutely right. It's because the index is stocked as integer and the file name is a string. You must do a conversion of either the id to be an int or the index to be a list of array. I'll edit the post as well. So you can change `id not in df_calc.index` by either `int(id) not in df_calc.index` or `id not in df_calc.index.values.astype('str')`

Comment: I modified the `id_from_file` to return a `int(name[-10:-4])` and it worked like a charm!

Comment: As I told in the post, doing int(name[..]) will work as long as the id is always of the same length, and at the same position, doing the regex is "better" because it will work for any size of id at the end of your file name between the I and the file extension .nii

Comment: I ended up using regex for that reason. Some ID numbers had 6 digits, but a few other had 7, which compromised the whole thing. Thanks man

Answer (score 0):

**--------- NEW ANSWER WITH A SIMPLE SCRIPT ----------**

Tested on MacOS:

Just export your 2 columns to a file named **map.csv** and format it like this:

```
old_file1.txt,new_file1.txt
old_file2.txt,new_file2.txt
old_file3.txt,new_file3.txt
```

create the shell script **rename.sh** and change the variables folder_path, csv_file and file_extension:

```
#!/bin/bash

folder_path="path/to/your/files/"
csv_file="path/to/map/file/map.csv"
file_extension=".jpg"

while IFS=',' read -r old_file new_file
do
  mv "${folder_path}/${old_file}${file_extension}" "${folder_path}/${new_file}${file_extension}"
  echo "File ${old_file}${file_extension} renamed to ${new_file}${file_extension}."
done < "$csv_file"
```

start the script with `sh rename.sh`

and enjoy the magic ;-)